# Build queries in mongoose + node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I´m quite new with Node.js and MongoDB and I`m having trouble when build queries.

For example I want to filter the date of my object depending on the request. This is what I did:

```
var startDate = req.body.startDate;
var endDate = req.body.endDate;

let findParams = {
    userId:req.userId
};
if(startDate){
    findParams["start"] = { $gt: new Date(startDate)};
}
if(endDate){
    findParams["start"] = { $lt: new Date(endDate)};
}
if(startDate && endDate){
    findParams["start"] = { $gt: new Date(startDate),$lt: new Date(endDate)};
}
console.log(findParams);
WorkTime.find(findParams)
```

I have to build the "start" param every time depending on what the user sends. If the user sends both values (startDate & endDate) I have to build the params object again.

What would be the optimal way to build this query?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is fine. There is no any "optimal" way, but a bit "elegant"

```
try {
    var startDate = req.body.startDate;
    var endDate   = req.body.endDate;

    let findParams = {
        userId: req.userId
    };

    if (startDate || endDate) {
        findParams["start"] = { };

        if (startDate) {
            findParams["start"]["$gt"] = new Date(startDate);
        }

        if (endDate) {
            findParams["start"]["$lt"] = new Date(endDate);
        }
    }

    console.log(findParams);
    WorkTime.find(findParams)
} (catch e) {
    console.log("Error occured: " + e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I find your solution way better!